Solve sparse system using more of the machine resources
I would like to know if it is possible to solve a sparse linear system with multiple threads in Julia.
Here is a redundant MRE
using LinearAlgebra
using SparseArrays

function create_sparse_poisson_matrix(n::Int)
    diagonal = spdiagm(0 => [2.0 for i in 1:n]) 
    off_diagonal = spdiagm(-1 => [-1.0 for i in 2:n])
    additional_subdiagonal = spdiagm(-3 => [-1.0 for i in 4:n]) 
    sparse_poisson_matrix = diagonal + off_diagonal + off_diagonal' + additional_subdiagonal + additional_subdiagonal'
    return sparse_poisson_matrix
end


n = 1000000 # Size of the matrix
A = create_sparse_poisson_matrix(n)
lu_A = lu(A , check=true);

x = zeros(n); 

for i = 1:1000
    x = lu_A \ x; 
end

On my machine it seams it is only be using one thread/core. How can I use the rest of the machine resources to solve a LU sparse system?

There's BLAS.set_num_threads. However, the end performance might be inferior to a, more involved, solution that leverages Julia's multithreading capabilities. See this Discourse post for some references.
I would recommend you take a look at LinearSolve.jl and try to adapt your code to use that instead. The corresponding short talk in JuliaCon 2022 by Chris Rackauckas gives some good pointers on what LinearSolve.jl does better compared to the builtin A\B. Note that for performance-related questions on solving such problems, there's a lot of parameters that could or could not have a great impact in performance. Generally, a good recommendation would be to a) provide as much details as possible about the specific use-case and b) use tools that will probably do a better job solving the problem out of the box.
